# About the closure of a single point set

Tags: general-topology

Recall that the closure of a set $S$ is the union of $S$ and its all limit points. For a given topological space $X$, $p$ is a point of $X$, is it possible that the closure of a single point set $\{p\}$ ,denoted by $\overline{\{p\}}$, has many points? And any continuous map $f$ from $\overline{\{p\}}$ to a topological space $Y$ is determined by $f(p)$, is this claim correct?
Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology

Comment: No,  the claim is not correct.  Again, the indiscrete space is a reason why.

Comment: @WilliamElliot With trivial topology, this is to say any point in the closure of {p} minus {p} is also a limit point, thank you!

Comment: @MiguelAtencia thank you!

Comment: @Jabin Provided the space S is multipoint , (cl p) - {p} = S.